# Not able to figure out why data posted twice to a api in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mongodb, api, post

I'm building an iOS app and posting a data to api. I'm facing a problem that i posted a once
but it is reflected twice on the server.And i have checked from rest clients that there is no error at the server side.

here is my code

```
 -  (void) next: (UIButton*) sender
  {
   NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"? &sportsname=%@&time=%@&venue=%@&date=%@&players=%@&addinfo=%@&userid=%@&gender=%@&recurring=%@",_selectedSport,_selectedTime,location,dateValue,max,info,UserId,_selectedGender,_selectedRecurring];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://yy.4.yyy.hh:iyiy/api/user/%@/host",UserId]]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"hostSubmit" sender:nil];
if(conn)
{
    NSLog(@"Connection successfull");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"connection could not be made");
 }
}
```

Comment: Your code seems fine.

Comment: @Mrunal yes it looks fine but i can't figure out where is the problem?

Comment: Put breakpoint on the code and use `bt` debugger console command to look who call your function twice

Comment: Is your problem resolved? If not do let me know.. I know solution. also let me know how you are calling method... **I believe its not action on UIButton as I don't see IBAction**

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy to link the same action twice in a button. Look at the actions tab in interface builder and make sure you haven't linked your button to your next: action twice.

Failing that, add a log statement at the beginning of the method "entering method 'next:'" and see if you see the log twice. If you do, go figure out why.